# Using indices with a pointer without dereferencing

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am looking at a function that makes an identity matrix, but I am confused on some of the syntax that is being used.

```
/* make an identity matrix of ints */
real      **id_mat(int dim) {
    int         row, col;
    real      **mat;

    mat = (real **) alloc2d(dim, dim, sizeof(real));
    if(mat == NULL)
        return (mat);

    for(row = 0; row < dim; row++)
        for(col = 0; col < dim; col++)
            mat[row][col] = (row == col ? 1.0 : 0.0); /* here */

    return (mat);
}
```

I am confused why `mat` is not being dereferenced to assign the row/column values. `mat` stores an address to a pointer, which I presume the goal is to keep the value changed outside of the function, so how does one build an array from an address? Should it not be `**mat[row][col] = (row == col ? 1.0 : 0.0);`? If not, why does this not work?

Comment: @xing real is a typedef for double and alloc2d is another function that the author wrote to allocate memory

Comment: Yep it works fine, was just wondering moreso about the why aspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am confused why mat is not being dereferenced to assign the row/column values.

`mat` is indeed being dereferenced with the line:

```
mat[row][col] = (row == col ? 1.0 : 0.0); /* here */
```

In C, the syntax `a[i]` is equivalent to `*((a) + (i))`, so what you have there is:

```
*(*((mat) + (row)) + (col)) = ...;
```

In fact, since addition is commutative (even for addresses), you could just as easily have `row[mat][col]`. For example, observe the array access syntax as well as the output for the following code:

```
int a[10][10];
int i = 0;

memset(a, 0, 10 * 10 * sizeof(int));

i[a][5] = 100;

printf("%d\n", 0[a][5]);
```